# call vscode extension activation script from command line

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to bundle the completely installed version of vsliveshare. To do that, I have to run the extension activation once because that downloads & installs additional files into the extension folder.

Now my instinct was to just run

```
% echo "require('./out/src/extension').activate()" | node
```

but that does not work out:

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
...
```

I've done a `npm install` and the vscode module is present in node_modules.

Is there any trick I can use to get this to execute from the command line without having to run vscode itself?